# AR(p) with white noise error term -- always covariance stationary?

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, time-series

Is it always true that an AR(p) process with a white noise error will be covariance stationary?

Comment: No it is not always true.

Comment: But it is true whenever we have P roots inside the unit circle?

Comment: Hi: If any of the roots of the AR(p) are outside the unit circle, then the AR(p) is not stationary in mean which means that it;s definitely not covariance stationary.

Comment: I should add that an AR(p) with all roots inside the unit circle is, by definition, covariance stationary  because  the covariance of $y_{t}$ and $y_{s}$ is only a function of $(t-s)$.

Comment: Yes, this is correct if we are only talking about stochastic trends but not if the process also has a deterministic trend. It could have all roots within the unit circle but if there is still a deterministic trend then the process would still not be covariance stationary.